# How to run an external library into different nodes?[MPI]

Tags: mpi, cluster-computing, openmpi, rocks

I need to write a C MPI code that use many functions of a library (specifically, it's [Parasail](https://github.com/jeffdaily/parasail)), but my cluster has three different processors, a front-end with Intel Xeon, 16 nodes with Intel i3 and 8 nodes with Intel Pentium-D.
How Should I compile this library and write the c code to run in all my 24 nodes?

I use OpenMPI and Rocks distribution.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should refer to your cluster's documentation. This is nothing that could be generally answered without knowing way more specifics about the infrastructure.

Comment: There's no cluster documentation, I mean, it's 25 computers of the lab and we installed the Rocks plataform. The only documentations I can see is Rocks documentation and OpenMPI documentation. Was that documentation you are refering to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have several options, and some are compiler dependent :

1. build a library specifically for the Pentium-D (since ISA is
   backward compatible)
2. build a "fat binary", this is a single binary
   optimized for several architectures. it is bigger, but run
   efficiently everywhere
3. build one optimized and shared library **per
   architecture** and install it on the local filesystem of all the
   nodes, so each node will automagically use the one that fits best

That being said, keep it mind most MPI applications run at the speed of the slowest node, so generally speaking, running an MPI app on both old and new hardware is suboptimal.